# Extension to the wobbly table theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, recreational-mathematics

I recently learned of the wobbly table theorem, I won't explain it here but Numberphile has [a great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuF-WB7mD6k) on it.

But if one were to expand it could it be possible to have a stable table with n number of legs after just rotating it?

I believe at some point you couldn't because the number of legs would be so large it would just form a hollow cube without one face and regard less of how you rotate it, it would remain unstable.

Comment: Three legs on the ground uniquely defines the table orientation and therefore the height of all the other legs. The positions where the heights of these other legs are zero need not be the same. So you are guaranteed to be able to find four legs on the ground by rotating, there is no guarantee that you can have more than 4.